# Writing Zend Framework 1.12 mysql "replace"

Tags: mysql, zend-framework

I want to write replace query to update or insert multiple rows data. How can I write this in zend framework 1.12.

Is there any options like giving array values so that it can insert/ update multiple rows at the same time?. Please help me to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`update`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.table.html#zend.db.table.update) method of the [Table class](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.table.html).

For example, if we wanted to give users with primary keys (field `id`) of 1, 2, 3 the name (field `name`) of Bob:

```
$users = new Users();

$data = array(
    'name'      => 'Bob'
);

$where = array(
    sprintf('id IN (%s)', implode(',', array(1,2,3)))
);        

$users->update($data, $where);
```

If necessary, quote the conditional(s) to prevent SQL injections. You can also update rows directly from a database adapter instance, see [Zend_Db_Adapter](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.adapter.html#zend.db.adapter.write.update).

Note: [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) allows one to use any data type that has an appropriate string representation.